# JavaScript - Return string value from event listeners

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, event-handling

In my Angular App I want to return string value (error message) from an event listener and assign it to a variable.

```
errorMessage: string = ''; // my variable
```

im trying to assign the error message to the variable above but its not assigning anything

```
ngOnInit() {

this.errorMessage = CustomHandler.on("error", function(event: {}) {

console.log(event.message) // The field has an error
return JSON.stringify(event.message)

});

}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean this just isn't how javascript works. Hard to say 100% since we don't know what CustomHandler.on() returns, but its very unlikely it returns the return value from your function. In theory becuse the event hasn't happened yet, but will in the future.

Don't really know exactly what you want to do, but you probably want something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  CustomHandler.on("error", (event: {}) => {
    console.log(event.message) // The field has an error
    this.errorMessage = JSON.stringify(event.message)
  });
}
```

In theory now if ngOnInit has been called and also the event you are handling occurs, this.errorMessage will contain the stringified message.

Comment: Yes, that's what im trying to do but i dont have access to this.errorMessage within the event function due to the scope

Comment: @johnsmith How is that possible? This should work just fine. Did you actually try this exact code? Arrow functions don't create their own scope, should be fine.

Comment: my bad, I wasn't implementing it correctly. Arrow method worked! :) Voted up and ticked! @rob

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting event object to be an empty object when you do this

```
this.errorMessage = CustomHandler.on("error", function(event: {}) {
```

can you try instead doing this

```
this.errorMessage = CustomHandler.on("error", function(event) {
```

Comment: That doesn't work because we have to specify the type. I have changed it to event: Event and event: any but same thing, it doesn't assign

Comment: Try checking if you have the correct function scope. Without seeing full code, it is hard to interpret where you are setting errorMessage: string= ''" an d expecting it to be returned.